# vBulletin forum page edit site

Tags: vbulletin

When we load forum page it gives console errors.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

Also when I do edit site it gives me error like:

**error_information_x**

I am working with **vBulletin version 5.**

Please anyone who have any idea, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been resolved by below link.

https://www.vbulletin.com/issue.php?issueid=1487395&authcode=4334246f